# NullPointerException in OnCreate of inherited Activity

Tags: android

Note: The title of this was changed to better reflect the actual problem.

I've run into a tricky nullPointerException - hoping someone here can give me an idea as to what is going wrong, as I am not successful in recreating the error so that I can get a debug stack trace.

The stack traces in the developer dashboard all indicate that the app is throwing a NullPointerException in onCreate from an Activity subclass (e.g., I have AActivity and BActivity both inheriting from BaseActivity which throws the exception). Presumably this is happening when the app is being resumed after having been thrown out of memory - at least that is my best guess. Although one user reports getting this error immediately on launching the app.

The onCreate function looks as follows:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.camp_ = MyApplication.getInstance().camp();
        if (this.camp_ == null) {
            this.finish();
            return;
        }
        if (!this.camp_.isSane()) {
            this.finish();
            return;
        }
    }
```

That's essentially it. MyApplication is the Application for the app; getInstance returns a pointer to the instance, or throws an IllegalStateException if the instance is null. isSane() essentially checks whether some of the variables in this.camp_ are null and returns false if the latter is the case.

I can't for the life of me see how this can throw a NullPointerException, but... it apparently does. It's my most frequent cause of error reports at the moment - but I've so far not had any luck provoking the issue myself (a problem I've frequently had with these bugs that only occur when the app restarts after having been wiped from memory).

[Edit 1]

Example stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.michael.android.app/com.michael.android.app.gui.GreetActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.michael.android.app.gui.BaseActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at com.michael.android.app.gui.GreetActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
... 11 more
```

As mentioned BaseActivity is inherited, so there are several variants of this same basic pattern of stack trace. onResume essentially does the same check for validity of the this.camp_ object - there is no onDestroy or onPause code in BaseActivity.

[Edit 2]

The getInstance code looks as follows:

```
public static MyApplication getInstance() {
    checkInstance();
    return instance_;
}

private static void checkInstance() {
    if (instance_ == null)
        throw new IllegalStateException("MyApplication not created yet!");
}
```

If instance was null, it should be returning an IllegalStateException, not a NPE.

Not really sure this is relevant, but here's a snip of the Application class.

[Edit 3]

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    // Instance 
    private static MyApplication instance_ = null;
    private Camp camp_ = null;

    public static MyApplication getInstance() {
        checkInstance();
        return instance_;
    }

    private static void checkInstance() {
        if (instance_ == null)
            throw new IllegalStateException("MyApplication not created yet!");
    }


    // Campaign
    public Camp camp() {
        return this.camp_;
    }

    private void parseSettings() {
        if (getFileStreamPath("settings.xml").exists()) {
            InputStream istream = null;
            try {
                istream = openFileInput("settings.xml");
                /* Get a SAXParser from the SAXPArserFactory. */
                SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
                /* Get the XMLReader of the SAXParser we created. */
                XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
                /* Create a new ContentHandler and apply it to the XML-Reader */
                SettingsHandler handler = new SettingsHandler();
                xr.setContentHandler(handler);
                xr.parse(new InputSource(istream));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("MyApplication", "File not found exception: settings.xml");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("MyApplication", "Exception thrown when decoding file settings.xml");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void saveSettings() {
        // ...
    }   

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // Set the instance
        instance_ = this;
        BaseActivity.flurryId = flurryId;
        parseSettings();
    }

    public void setCamp(Camp c) {
        this.camp_ = c;
    }

}
```

I'm wondering if the issue may be something with the this reference being somehow incorrect in the onCreate methods.

Comment: I think that what is null is `MyApplication.getInstance()`.

Comment: But how can it be null, when getInstance() does if (instance_ == null) throw new IllegalStateException("MyApplication not created yet!")? That makes no sense to me. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that I had a BaseActivity (which is where the NPE occurs), which would be inherited by AActivity and BActivity.

Apparently, the issue was with calling "finish()" in the onCreate of BaseActivity. Moving the finish() calls out of the BaseActivity onCreate calls and instead checking whether to call finish() in AActivity and BActivity fixed the problem.

Hopefully this is of use to someone else. I will change the title to better reflect the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

In this code only `MyApplication.getInstance()` returning null would lead to a NullPointerException. If you want a more detailed explanation please supply the stacktrace and the MyApplication Singleton code.

I am not sure why you are implementing a Singleton pattern on the MyApplication class anyway. Your application is only going to run once, so no need for a Singleton. If you want to access your application instance in an activity you can use
    MyApplication application = (MyApplication) getApplication();

Comment: As I replied to Cristian, I don't see how this is possible. Added the getInstance code from MyApplication.

Comment: Regarding the second point; convenience/personal preference. I find  MyApplication.getInstance() much easier to read and use in the code  - and getApplication() is not really useful if you have to get the application without direct access to a Context.

Comment: Very tricky problem. I guess you have a point with the Singleton pattern (see http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=1218).

Comment: Can you provide the full code of the MyApplication class? Because this only occurs sporadically I would guess it is a threading issue. Maybe it is related to the fact that this is not a true Singleton, since the constructor of MyApplication cannot be private. Hence you can have an instance of MyApplication that doesn't have an instance_, because that is created in the - my assumption - onCreate() method? I agree this should throw an IllegalStateException.

Comment: Most of the code added now except for a few functions that are completely irrelevant in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have at least a stacktrace report? You're talking about a NPE but actually not where it is thrown. Sure you present the affected code?

My guess would be that you're relying on some code from previous activities, but since your application is restored the previous activities are not instantiated and the data is `null`. So I would recommend to search in `onDestroy` for such data dependent code because it will be called too.

Comment: Added an example of a stacktrace.

Comment: Ahh, okay, now I start to understand what you mean. I'll keep a look at that. (But it's time to catch some sleep now ;-)